# VBA Clear Macro Not Working Unless on Filter Criteria Sheet

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I built a userform for doing a simple filter search. I can open the form and filter while any worksheet is selected. However, when I use the clear button from the userform but I am not on the filter criteria worksheet (Sheet1) I get a "1004: Select Method of Range class failed" error for the first select statement.

```
Sub Clear()
'
' Clear Macro
'
    Sheet1.Range("A2:H2").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Sheet1.Range("A5:H1725").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Sheet1.Range("A2").Select

End Sub
```

Am I forced to have the filter sheet open or is my code just not working correctly? I wanted to have a sheet with the open form button with the data (Sheet2) and filter criteria (Sheet1) hidden.

On cmdClear_click() I am calling this before running Clear:

```
Private Sub ClearForm()
'
'clear values
    With Me
        .txtCustId = ""
        .txtCustName = ""
        .txtAddress = ""
        .txtCity = ""
        .txtState = ""
        .txtZip = ""
        .txtCountry = ""
        .txtStatus = ""
    End With
End Sub
```

The only other thing I can think of that may screw it up is the Me....

Comment: In general, you want to [avoid using activate and select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) in your code

Comment: As mentioned it is better to avoid using Activate and Select, however for a quick fix, instead of `Sheet1` can you try `ActiveSheet` like `ActiveSheet.Range(...).Select` Also, do you have this code in a separate Module or inside a Sheet Module?

Comment: @RicardoA: It is in a separate module and not a sheet module.What happens if the form is not looking to the active sheet?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad: i know of this question and answer but it is beyond my comprehension right now

Comment: Then you avoid using Select, my answer i just posted has it that way, reply to the answer if any issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.Select` only works if you are on the specified Sheet, in your code you are using `Sheet1(..).Select` meaning that you are selecting something on Sheet1, if you are on a different Sheet/Tab it will fail. To avoid this,  you have to avoid using Select.

Same outcome without Select:

```
Sub Clear()
'
' Clear Macro
    With ThisWorkbook
        'Replace "Sheet1" if you have renamed your Sheet to something else
        .Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:H2").ClearContents
        .Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A5:H1725").ClearContents
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: If you are only working with Sheet1 you can call the workbook and the sheet together: `With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")` and continue with just `.Range("A2:H2").ClearContents`. Depending on how much you do inside the `With` sometimes its a lot easier/cleaner calling the sheet name too.